# Convert <LookAt> to <Camera>

Tags: google-earth

Is there a way to convert LookAt to Camera element?
We want to define drone aerial POI with Google Earth.

I can define my views with Snapshot.
Problem is this is then defined with a  element.
I need the  equivalent where the  drone has to fly to.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/cameras

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to create the camera element, with an "Add Photo" I can configure a camera KML element.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://earthexplorer.world  Earth Explorer 3D Map app with augmented reality it supports more formats than KML like offline mbtiles and gpkg and other formats and mapping services